# Input Chinese characters into table directly via DB2 Control Center

Tags: db2, cjk

Pardon me if this question sounds trivial, I don't have any experience working with Unicode encoding/decoding before.

I have a Java web application that is already complete. It has some web forms to let the user input data and save them to the database. Currently it works well for most kinds of data, but failed to input Chinese characters correctly.

What I am trying to to is to figure out where things go wrong. I started with DB2, trying to paste a Chinese character that I copied from a Chinese website, which was UTF-8 encoded, to a table using Control Center.  It turns to a sequence of vertical bars, which look like the L character in bold Arial font. I'm using DB2 ver 9 UDB for Windows.

My question is: Do I need to enable Unicode support for DB2 and how to do that? Do I need to specify the charset as UTF-8 when using JDBC to save the data, and how this can be done?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the instructions from IBM:

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21200211

Figure 1: Open Table dialog from DB2 Control Center, showing boxes instead of Traditional Chinese characters in an English environment.

To use a Unicode font installed, the font.properties file has to be updated accordingly.

For instance, TwinBridege Traditional Chinese Ming Font (TSC FMing S TT) is installed to display Traditional Chinese characters. The font name can be found in C:\Windows\Fonts on XP or C:\WINNT\Fonts on Windows 2000:

To use the font, the mapping in 'sansserif.*' and 'dialog.*' section has to include the font name 'TSC FMing S TT'. Update the font.properties as follows:

Example:

```
dialog.0=Arial
dialog.1=Arial Unicode MS
dialog.2=Lucida Sans Regular
dialog.3=Simsun (Founder Extended)
#Add the following line to map 'dialog' to use TSC FMing S TT font.
dialog.4=TSC FMing S TT

dialog.italic.0=Arial Italic
dialog.italic.1=Arial Unicode MS
dialog.italic.2=Lucida Sans Oblique
#Add the following line to map 'dialog' to use TSC FMing S TT font.
dialog.italic.3=TSC FMing S TT

dialog.bold.0=Arial Bold
dialog.bold.1=Arial Unicode MS
dialog.bold.2=Lucida Sans Regular
#Add the following line to map 'dialog' to use TSC FMing S TT font.
dialog.bold.3=TSC FMing S TT

dialog.bolditalic.0=Arial Bold Italic
dialog.bolditalic.1=Arial Unicode MS
dialog.bolditalic.2=Lucida Sans Oblique
```

Add the following line to map 'dialog' to use TSC FMing S TT font.

```
dialog.bolditalic.3=TSC FMing S TT
```

With the font installed, and font mapped in font.properties, the Unicode data can be rendered in the Control Center in English...

Figure 3: Open Table dialog from DB2 Control Center, showing Traditional Chinese characters in an English environment after the setup.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation (meant to vote up but found out I don't have enough reputation point:)

Comment: oh, don't worry, mind selecting the answer though? would be quite helpful :) (green checkmark of goodness) And thanks :)

Comment: Actually I didn't try your instructions yet because I'm not at work for now, and I don't have DB2 installation package here in my own PC. I just feel that it will work (99%:). Can't wait til Monday to try it and 'accept' your answer:)

Comment: The file name has been change. It is now fontconfig.properties.src under "Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\jdk\jre\lib"